# List of NSDate Objects in Realm

Tags: arrays, list, nsdate, realm

I am looking to create an array of NSDate objects in Realm.  I have tried to create one with:

```
dynamic var listOfDates : [NSDate] = []
```

Yet this returns a run-time error stating that this is not allowed.

I figured you could create another Realm Object, rDate, that only has one property - a NSDate and then it could be used like so:  let Dates = List().  However, this seems like the wrong approach, does anyone know the proper way to create a list of NSDate in Realm?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) property, which is the container type in Realm used to define to-many relationships.

```
class Date: Object {
  dynamic var value = NSDate()
}
class MyObject: Object {
  let listOfDates = List<Date>()
}
```

Realm is working on adding functionality for storing lists of primitives directly ([#1120](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1120)), which would allow `let listOfDates = List<NSDate>()` but that's not ready just yet.

Comment: Great!  This is what I was thinking :)